# Not able to login to azure webapp after for azure database failover

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, failover, geo-replication

I have Configured Application Connection String.

```
 metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=azuresqlfailover.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=signagedb;User ID=username;Password=Password1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
```

Initially i am able to login to Web Application, But when i perform fail over, we are not able to login to webapp.

In Database we have table for user Name and password. Web App will be authenticated from Database table.

Comment: Please give more information about sql profiling (use DVM to query), how do you store password in SQL table (hash?), and how your web application authenticates to that table (execute stored procedure?)

Comment: We have table for user Credentials, we are storing SQL Credentials as plain Text. When we tried to Sign to the page. Will check for username and password, If user details exist in table, user will be able to login to web page.

we are not able to login to the page, as the web site is not able to read data in Database.

Comment: Could you make a remotely stored procedure against the fail-over database? Just perform a query only. This is to make sure the database is accessible with authorized username and password specified.